# Apple Division CSES Qustion SOlution

Tags: c++, operators, bit, explain

so this is the link of the question https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1623.
What does this code snippet mean??  :-

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << n; ++i)
{
    ll cs = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        if (i >> j & 1)
            cs += p[j];
    if (cs <= s / 2)
        ans = max(ans, cs);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which line of the code do you meant? just copy the code snippet you want to know, this make it easier to answer.

Comment: okay i did that

Answer (score 4):

It iterates through every possible combination of an array and finds the closest sum equivalent to half of the total sum.